# how to separate a string in php

Tags: php

sometext( [key] => value which content number and alphabates )

from above,i want only value part by using explode function for only one time.Is it possible.
or any other function is present in php.

Comment: Can you give us an example for input and expected output?

Comment: @Gumbo you beat me to it, was just about to say the same myself!

Comment: asns([this_is_key]=>abc123hfj)  //Input

abc123hfj        //output

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$arr = explode('=>',$str);
$arr = explode(')',$arr[1]);
echo "Value = ".$arr[0]; // prints: Value = abc123hfj
```

or using regex you can do:

```
$str = 'asns([this_is_key]=>abc123hfj)';
if(preg_match('/=>([^)]*)\)/',$str,$matches)) {
        echo "Value = ".$matches[1]; // prints: Value = abc123hfj
}
```

If you want to use explode just once you can do:

```
$arr = explode('=>',chop($str,')'));
echo "Value = ".$arr[1]; // prints: Value = abc123hfj
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get array 
(1 => "value",
2 => "which content number and alphabates");

You can just search first occurrence of a whitespace, and call two substr functions. Something like that

```
$string = 'value which content number and alphabates';
$result = array(substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ' ')), substr($string, strpos($string, ' ')+1));
print_r($result);
```

Or you can do explode and and implode exploded array, after unsetting array key 0, like so

```
$string = 'value which content number and alphabates';
$chunk = explode(' ', $string);
$result = array();
$result[] = $chunk[0];
unset($chunk[0]);
$result[] = implode(' ', $chunk);
print_r($result);
```

Or if you want to get just part "value" from your string, just use list

```
$string = 'value which content number and alphabates';
list($result) = explode(' ', $string);
echo $result;
```